# Not sure if correct httpd-vhosts.conf file is being read in OS X

Tags: macos, apache, vhosts

I'm trying to get the Apache server that comes with OS X to work for my local website. No matter what I change the file `httpd-vhosts.conf` to, when I run `httpd -S` in Terminal it says my virtual host syntax is OK. I typed in a bunch of random characters into the file, restarted Apache, and it still says my configuration is OK.

First I edited `/private/etc/hosts` and added this line underneath `127.0.0.1 localhost`:

```
127.0.0.1   mysite
```

Then I edited `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. I uncommented this line:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I also uncommented the PHP5 line to enable PHP.

Next I edited `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and set up my virtual hosts. After restarting apache, my virtual hosts were not working and running `httpd -S` said my virtual hosts syntax was OK. No erros in the Apache error log. This is what the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file contained:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Gavin/Web"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Gavin/Web/mysite/public_html"
    ServerName mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

No matter what I did, my virtual hosts would not work. So I tried changing `httpd-vhosts.conf` to this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost @*^#*&^#$>
    (#*&#*$&@(*UOSKSFLKSFJLJF##*(&
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted Apache using `sudo apachectl restart` and then ran `apachectl -S` and it says:

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Gavins-MacBook-Pro.local for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
```

Obviously my httpd-vhosts.conf file is not OK, so which file is it loading? In Terminal I ran `httpd -V|grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE` and it returned:

```
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

That's obviously the correct `httpd.conf` file, so what's going on here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything, and nothing working, I downloaded an app for managing vhosts. It's expensive but has a free 14 day trial (just google search for it and you'll find it). Anyway, the app changed my httpd-vhosts.conf file to this and now it's working:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/Users/Gavin/Web/">
Allow From All
AllowOverride All
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "localhost"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Gavin/Web"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/Users/Gavin/Web/mysite/public_html/">
Allow From All
AllowOverride All
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "mysite"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Gavin/Web/mysite/public_html"
</VirtualHost>
```

I read 20+ tutorials on setting up vhosts on OS X and none of them worked. This tool worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your should look forward '/private/etc/apache2/users/' folder. There is a special (Your username).conf where you can add your virtual hosts.

Comment: Would I change this file to be exactly like the httpd-vhosts.conf file, including the `NameVirtualHost *:80` line and `localhost` definition as well?

Comment: I've read about 20 tutorials on setting up virtual hosts in Apache on OS X and none of them said to do this. Are you sure that's necessary?

Comment: However, this solution is something like 'do it but I don't know why'.You should look in your httpd.conf and find in what order conf files are included and if it's inclusion is uncommented.

Comment: Still whatever I changed the virtual hosts to it seems to not do anything. Even changing my Gavin.conf file to `2398u2xX@R#@#XX@` still starts Apache OK and doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Try this in the Terminal and post output here:
sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -e Debug -E /dev/stdout

Comment: Have you changed back your httpd-vhosts.conf or there were errors ? Cause sometimes (I don't know why) apachectl doesn't work, so you have to kill https by pid and then start it again.(So maybe the changes that you've made haven't affect apache that you are running right now and everything is ok, but you are using pre-updated conf).

Comment: There weren't any errors. I just download an os x vhost management app and added my vhosts in there and it worked :) Thank you for trying to help. I'm going to post an answer to this question with what the app changed my httpd-vhosts.conf file to.